# Does postfix natively included in Centos 7 support mysql?

Tags: postfix

I read this [post](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mariadb-on-centos-7/#install-required-packages),mentioned:

> The version of Postfix included in the main CentOS repository does not include support for MariaDB; therefore, you will need install Postfix from the CentOS Plus repository.

But,In a newly install(from ISO) Centos7 server,run `postconf -m`, the result as below:

```
[root@localhost ~]# postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
internal
ldap
memcache
mysql
nis
pcre
proxy
regexp
socketmap
static
tcp
texthash
unix
```

I can see `mysql`,does postfix natively included in Centos 7 support mysql?

Comment: That doc is obviously wrong; you already proved it yourself!

Comment: I am newbie,then I ask authority